# Why does IntelliJ change line separators on save from CRLF to LF

Tags: git, intellij-idea

- I do not have IntelliJ's "Save Actions" plugin installed.
- `git config core.autocrlf` => true
- `git config core.safecrlf` => true
- Running Windows 10 for my sins
- The corresponding `.gitattributes` file has `* text=auto`

I have a git repo checked out onto a Windows box. IntelliJ initially shows the files are initially CRLF line-separators (correct as I'm running Windows).

- When I save an existing (Java) file in IntelliJ, the line-separators are CHANGED TO LF.
- When I save the file via Notepad++ or VSCode, the line-separators are NOT CHANGED.

This means that when I do a `git add` it fails with `fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in <file>`.

FWIW

- Checkout git repo via Windows Console, or Git Bash console makes no difference
- At some point in the past I cloned via Ubuntu on WSL, but I've since done a clean clone into a new folder.

Are there any IntelliJ settings to stop it changing CRLF -> LF?

The workaround is to use `--ignore-errors`, e.g. `git add --ignore-errors <file>` but that's annoying.

Comment: What's your [line separator](https://i.imgur.com/zFIlgUR.png) setting?

Comment: It's "System-Dependent". I changed it to "Windows" on the off chance. No difference.

Comment: Any `.editorconfig` files in the project that override the default?

Comment: @CrazyCoder that did it. Wonderful, thanks! If you write up an answer, I'll accept it. Good old IntelliJ doing the right thing - Eclipse doesn't (other devs use Eclipse)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA honors `.editorconfig` configuration by default which overrides IDE formatting settings.

You can either [disable this feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADf1W.png) or remove this file from the project.